# Why is "SSL Settings" feature delegation disabled by default?

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-config, security

I would like to specify SSL flags in application web.config file. Actually, I would like to get something like this:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <location path="">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <access sslFlags="Ssl" />
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    <location path="Public">
        <system.webServer>
            <security>
                <access sslFlags="None" />
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
    ...
</configuration>
```

But I found that "SSL Settings" feature delegation is disabled by default.

So I'm wondering if it's dangerous to enable this or not. I can't imagine why this can be dangerous... But I'm confused with default IIS settings.